# How to post data to a react js application?

Tags: android, reactjs, android-webview, postman, postdata

I have an android application which will open a react js application in a web view. The android app will post JSON data to its web view which will render my react js application. However, I am not sure how I would fetch the data from a post to the Android web view from my react js application.
I tried posting some JSON data to my react js application using POSTMAN which returns a 404 page not found.
The android application will use something similar to the below code to post to the webview:-

```
 WebView webview = new WebView(this);
 setContentView(webview);
 String url = "http://www.example.com";
 String postData = "username=" + URLEncoder.encode(my_username, "UTF-8") + "&password=" + URLEncoder.encode(my_password, "UTF-8");
 webview.postUrl(url,postData.getBytes());
```

Please find attached a copy of the screenshot for my POSTMAN post request.[image]

Any help or suggestion is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Probably you should ask this question under `android` tag, because it's impossible to read POST body in front-end javascript applications - it could be only proceed on server side.

Comment: You can use sockets to communicate with your application but I don't think it's not what you want. As @Dracontis mentioned, this process is made the opposite direction.

Comment: You can't `POST` anything to a `React.js` application - it's not a server. If you want to share some data between your `Android` and `React.js` application, you need to have a server that's going to sit in the middle and pass information from one end to another, with something like sockets for example - https://socket.io

Comment: @Dracontis thank you for the prompt response. I have updated my question and I hope I find a solution here.